# Best way to structure table for forum

Tags: mysql

I am practising in writing a simple forum and just can't decide on table structure.
Currently I have this:

```
        id  int(11)     AUTO_INCREMENT      
        title   varchar(56) 
        group_id    int(11)
        group_parent    tinyint(1)
        access_from int(11) 
        alliance_forum  tinyint(1)           
        alliance_id int(11)
        alliance_role_access    int(11)
```

Group parent is a 0 or 1 column which states wherever a forum is parent of forums, and group id is for group forums whch reffers to same table to record with group parent set to 1.
Alliance forum is same as group parent, as the alliance id,and access column are for access control.
Which would be the best and perfomant way of restructuring this? Should I mak 3 different tables for alliance forums, forum_groups and group_forums or keep it this way?